# Java 8 stream unpredictable performance drop with no obvious reason

Tags: java, performance, lambda, java-stream, jmh

I am using Java 8 streams to iterate over a list with sublists. The outer list size varies between 100 to 1000 (different test runs) and the inner list size is always 5.

There are 2 benchmark runs which show unexpected performance deviations.

```
package benchmark;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

@Threads(32)
@Warmup(iterations = 25)
@Measurement(iterations = 5)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
public class StreamBenchmark {
    @Param({"700", "600", "500", "400", "300", "200", "100"})
    int outerListSizeParam;
    final static int INNER_LIST_SIZE = 5;
    List<List<Integer>> list;

    Random rand() {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    }

    final BinaryOperator<Integer> reducer = (val1, val2) -> val1 + val2;

    final Supplier<List<Integer>> supplier = () -> IntStream
            .range(0, INNER_LIST_SIZE)
            .mapToObj(ptr -> rand().nextInt(100))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    @Setup
    public void init() throws IOException {
        list = IntStream
                .range(0, outerListSizeParam)
                .mapToObj(i -> supplier.get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void loop(Blackhole bh) throws Exception {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Integer> innerList : list) {
            if (innerList.stream().reduce(reducer).orElse(0) == rand().nextInt(2000)) {
                res.add(innerList);
            }
        }

        bh.consume(res);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stream(Blackhole bh) throws Exception {
        List<List<Integer>> res = list
                .stream()
                .filter(innerList -> innerList.stream().reduce(reducer).orElse(0) == rand().nextInt(2000))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        bh.consume(res);
    }
}
```

**Run 1**

```
    Benchmark               (outerListSizeParam)   Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     700  thrpt    5    22488.601 ?   1128.543  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     600  thrpt    5    26010.430 ?   1161.854  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     500  thrpt    5   361837.395 ?  12777.016  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     400  thrpt    5   451774.457 ?  22517.801  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     300  thrpt    5   744677.723 ?  23456.913  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     200  thrpt    5  1102075.707 ?  38678.994  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     100  thrpt    5  2334981.090 ? 100973.551  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   700  thrpt    5    22320.346 ?    496.432  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   600  thrpt    5    26091.609 ?   1044.868  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   500  thrpt    5    31961.096 ?    497.854  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   400  thrpt    5   377701.859 ?  11115.990  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   300  thrpt    5    53887.652 ?   1228.245  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   200  thrpt    5    78754.294 ?   2173.316  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   100  thrpt    5  1564899.788 ?  47369.698  ops/s
```

**Run 2**

```
    Benchmark               (outerListSizeParam)   Mode  Cnt        Score       Error  Units
    StreamBenchmark.loop                    1000  thrpt   10    16179.702 ?   260.134  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     700  thrpt   10    22924.319 ?   329.134  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     600  thrpt   10    26871.267 ?   416.464  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     500  thrpt   10   353043.221 ?  6628.980  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     300  thrpt   10   772234.261 ? 10075.536  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.loop                     100  thrpt   10  2357125.442 ? 30824.834  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                  1000  thrpt   10    15526.423 ?   147.454  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   700  thrpt   10    22347.898 ?   117.360  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   600  thrpt   10    26172.790 ?   229.745  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   500  thrpt   10    31643.518 ?   428.680  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   300  thrpt   10   536037.041 ?  6176.192  ops/s
    StreamBenchmark.stream                   100  thrpt   10   153619.054 ?  1450.839  ops/s
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is there a consistent, significant performance difference between loop+500 and loop+600 for both test runs?
2. Why in Run1 stream+400 and Run2 stream+300 is there a significant but inconsistent performance deviation?

It looks like the JIT sometimes makes suboptimal optimization decisions, causing a huge performance drop.

The test machine has 128GB RAM and 32 CPU cores:

```
    java version "1.8.0_45"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

    Architecture:          x86_64
    CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
    Byte Order:            Little Endian
    CPU(s):                32
    On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
    Thread(s) per core:    2
    Core(s) per socket:    8
    Socket(s):             2
    NUMA node(s):          2
    Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
    CPU family:            6
    Model:                 62
    Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz
    Stepping:              4
    CPU MHz:               1201.078
    CPU max MHz:           3400.0000
    CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
    BogoMIPS:              5201.67
    Virtualization:        VT-x
    L1d cache:             32K
    L1i cache:             32K
    L2 cache:              256K
    L3 cache:              20480K
    NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,16-23
    NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,24-31
```

P.S. Added benchmark with no stream. These tests (loop + stream + pureLoop) make me think that using streams and lambdas would require a lot of micro optimisation efforts and does not guarantee consistent performance anyway.

```
@Benchmark
public void pureLoop(Blackhole bh) throws Exception {
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Integer> innerList : list) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : innerList) {
            sum += i;
        }
        if (sum == rand().nextInt(2000))
            res.add(innerList);
    }

    bh.consume(res);
}
```

**Run 3 (pure loops)**

```
Benchmark                 (outerListSizeParam)   Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
StreamBenchmark.loop                      1000  thrpt    5     15848.277 ?    445.624  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       700  thrpt    5     22330.289 ?    484.554  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       600  thrpt    5     26353.565 ?    631.421  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       500  thrpt    5    358144.956 ?   8273.981  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       400  thrpt    5    591471.382 ?  17725.212  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       300  thrpt    5    785458.022 ?  23775.650  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       200  thrpt    5   1192328.880 ?  40006.056  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       100  thrpt    5   2330555.766 ?  73143.081  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                  1000  thrpt    5   1024629.128 ?   4387.106  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   700  thrpt    5   1495365.029 ?  31659.941  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   600  thrpt    5   1787432.825 ?  16611.868  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   500  thrpt    5   2087093.023 ?  20143.165  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   400  thrpt    5   2662946.999 ?  33326.079  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   300  thrpt    5   3657830.227 ?  55020.775  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   200  thrpt    5   5365706.786 ?  64404.783  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   100  thrpt    5  10477430.730 ? 187641.413  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                    1000  thrpt    5     15576.304 ?    250.620  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     700  thrpt    5     22286.965 ?   1153.734  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     600  thrpt    5     26109.258 ?    296.382  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     500  thrpt    5     31343.986 ?   1270.210  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     400  thrpt    5     39696.775 ?   1812.355  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     300  thrpt    5    536932.353 ?  41249.909  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     200  thrpt    5     77797.301 ?    976.641  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     100  thrpt    5    155387.348 ?   3182.841  ops/s
```

**Solution**: as recommended by apangin disabling [tiered compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html) made JIT results stable.

```
java -XX:-TieredCompilation -jar test-jmh.jar

Benchmark                 (outerListSizeParam)   Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
StreamBenchmark.loop                      1000  thrpt    5    160410.288 ?   4426.320  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       700  thrpt    5    230524.018 ?   4426.740  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       600  thrpt    5    266266.663 ?   9078.827  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       500  thrpt    5    324182.307 ?   8452.368  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       400  thrpt    5    400793.677 ?  12526.475  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       300  thrpt    5    534618.231 ?  25616.352  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       200  thrpt    5    803314.614 ?  33108.005  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.loop                       100  thrpt    5   1827400.764 ?  13868.253  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                  1000  thrpt    5   1126873.129 ?  33307.600  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   700  thrpt    5   1560200.150 ? 150146.319  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   600  thrpt    5   1848113.823 ?  16195.103  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   500  thrpt    5   2250201.116 ? 130995.240  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   400  thrpt    5   2839212.063 ? 142008.523  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   300  thrpt    5   3807436.825 ? 140612.798  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   200  thrpt    5   5724311.256 ?  77031.417  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.pureLoop                   100  thrpt    5  11718427.224 ? 101424.952  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                    1000  thrpt    5     16186.121 ?    249.806  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     700  thrpt    5     22071.884 ?    703.729  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     600  thrpt    5     25546.378 ?    472.804  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     500  thrpt    5     32271.659 ?    437.048  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     400  thrpt    5     39755.841 ?    506.207  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     300  thrpt    5     52309.706 ?   1271.206  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     200  thrpt    5     79277.532 ?   2040.740  ops/s
StreamBenchmark.stream                     100  thrpt    5    161244.347 ?   3882.619  ops/s
```

Comment: When I replaced `Collectors.toList` with `forEach(res::add)` at `stream` they start working with the same performance.

Comment: If you want to investigate codegen, look at `-XX:+PrintAssembly`. As you're running on a NUMA machine, you could try running only on one socket and see if the trends are the same.

Comment: Make sure to disable turbo boost for benchmarking. It does make a difference if your CPU runs as 2.6 GHz or at 3.4 GHz. Also consider adding a real loop based verison, that also does not use a reducer on the inner lists. ;-)

Comment: Not sure if turbo boost could cause 10 times performance gaps, also before each estimate there was jvm warmup for 25 iterations.

Comment: @user3707125 - What memory options are you using for your JVM?  Try using different options for `-Xmx` and `-Xms` and see what happens to your benchmark wnen using `Collectors.toList`.

Comment: Added test result with -Xms4G, Xmx4G. I have tested with different JIT settings, some of them gave higher probability of performance boost, but it was random success, which could not be predictably reproduced.

Comment: Have you tried disabling JIT (-Xint)?

Comment: Added run with disabled JIT. It equally slows down all tests and avoids random performance gaps.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This effect is caused by [Type Profile Pollution](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/MethodData). Let me explain on a simplified benchmark:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class Streams {
    @Param({"500", "520"})
    int iterations;

    @Setup
    public void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            Stream.empty().reduce((x, y) -> x);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long loop() {
        return Stream.empty().count();
    }
}
```

Though `iteration` parameter here changes very slightly and it does not affect the main benchmark loop, the results expose very surprising 2.5x performance degradation:

```
Benchmark     (iterations)   Mode  Cnt      Score     Error   Units
Streams.loop           500  thrpt    5  29491,039 ± 240,953  ops/ms
Streams.loop           520  thrpt    5  11867,860 ± 344,779  ops/ms
```

Now let's run JMH with `-prof perfasm` option to see the hottest code regions:

Fast case (iterations = 500):

```
....[Hottest Methods (after inlining)]..................................
 48,66%  bench.generated.Streams_loop::loop_thrpt_jmhStub
 23,14%  <unknown>
  2,99%  java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference::<init>
  1,98%  org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole::consume
  1,68%  java.util.Objects::requireNonNull
  0,65%  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline::evaluate
```

Slow case (iterations = 520):

```
....[Hottest Methods (after inlining)]..................................
 40,09%  java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp::evaluateSequential
 22,02%  <unknown>
 17,61%  bench.generated.Streams_loop::loop_thrpt_jmhStub
  1,25%  org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole::consume
  0,74%  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline::evaluate
```

Looks like the slow case spends the most time in `ReduceOp.evaluateSequential` method that is not inlined. Furthermore, if we study the assembly code for this method we'll find that the longest operation is `checkcast`.

You know how HotSpot compiler works: before the JIT starts, a method is executed in interpreter for some time to collect the [profile data](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/MethodData), e.g. what methods are called, what classes are seen, what branches are taken etc. With Tiered compilation the profile is also collected in C1-compiled code. The profile is then used to generate C2-optimizied code. However if the application changes execution pattern in the middle, the generated code may be not optimal for the modified behavior.

Let's use `-XX:+PrintMethodData` (available in debug JVM) to compare the execution profiles:

```
----- Fast case -----
java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp::evaluateSequential(Ljava/util/stream/PipelineHelper;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  interpreter_invocation_count:    13382 
  invocation_counter:              13382 
  backedge_counter:                    0 
  mdo size: 552 bytes

0 aload_1
1 fast_aload_0
2 invokevirtual 3 <java/util/stream/ReduceOps$ReduceOp.makeSink()Ljava/util/stream/ReduceOps$AccumulatingSink;> 
  0   bci: 2    VirtualCallData     count(0) entries(1)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$8'(12870 1.00)
5 aload_2
6 invokevirtual 4 <java/util/stream/PipelineHelper.wrapAndCopyInto(Ljava/util/stream/Sink;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)Ljava/util/stream/Sink;> 
  48  bci: 6    VirtualCallData     count(0) entries(1)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline$5'(12870 1.00)
9 checkcast 5 <java/util/stream/ReduceOps$AccumulatingSink>
  96  bci: 9    ReceiverTypeData    count(0) entries(1)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$8ReducingSink'(12870 1.00)
12 invokeinterface 6 <java/util/stream/ReduceOps$AccumulatingSink.get()Ljava/lang/Object;> 
  144 bci: 12   VirtualCallData     count(0) entries(1)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$8ReducingSink'(12870 1.00)
17 areturn

----- Slow case -----
java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp::evaluateSequential(Ljava/util/stream/PipelineHelper;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  interpreter_invocation_count:    54751 
  invocation_counter:              54751 
  backedge_counter:                    0 
  mdo size: 552 bytes

0 aload_1
1 fast_aload_0
2 invokevirtual 3 <java/util/stream/ReduceOps$ReduceOp.makeSink()Ljava/util/stream/ReduceOps$AccumulatingSink;> 
  0   bci: 2    VirtualCallData     count(0) entries(2)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$2'(16 0.00)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$8'(54223 1.00)
5 aload_2
6 invokevirtual 4 <java/util/stream/PipelineHelper.wrapAndCopyInto(Ljava/util/stream/Sink;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)Ljava/util/stream/Sink;> 
  48  bci: 6    VirtualCallData     count(0) entries(2)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline$Head'(16 0.00)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline$5'(54223 1.00)
9 checkcast 5 <java/util/stream/ReduceOps$AccumulatingSink>
  96  bci: 9    ReceiverTypeData    count(0) entries(2)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$2ReducingSink'(16 0.00)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$8ReducingSink'(54228 1.00)
12 invokeinterface 6 <java/util/stream/ReduceOps$AccumulatingSink.get()Ljava/lang/Object;> 
  144 bci: 12   VirtualCallData     count(0) entries(2)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$2ReducingSink'(16 0.00)
                                    'java/util/stream/ReduceOps$8ReducingSink'(54228 1.00)
17 areturn
```

You see, the initialization loop ran too long that its statistics appeared in the execution profile: all virtual methods have two implementations and checkcast has also two different entries. In the fast case the profile is not polluted: all sites are monomorphic, and JIT can easily inline and optimize them.

The same is true for your original benchmark: longer stream operations in `init()` method polluted the profile. If you play with profile and tiered compilation options, the results can be quite different. For example, try

1. `-XX:-ProfileInterpreter`
2. `-XX:Tier3InvocationThreshold=1000`
3. `-XX:-TieredCompilation`

Finally, this problem is not unique. There are already multiple JVM bugs related to performance regressions due to profile pollution: [JDK-8015416](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015416), [JDK-8015417](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015417), [JDK-8059879](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059879)... Hope this will be improved in Java 9.

Comment: Damn, that's detailed. _You know how HotSpot compiler works_ Not really, so thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Could also be interesting to play with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize

Comment: Thanks for the answer @apangin. Has this been solved with Java 9 though ?